# Replacing The Blue Folder Icon With A Customised Image?

Tags: macos, preview, folders, customization

How can I select a JPEG image and use that to customise/replace the usual blue folder icon for a given folder (which additionally may even make it easier to tell folders apart, when looking for one)?

If this can be achieved without the use of a specific App, then all the better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Open the image that you would like to be the folder icon in Preview.
2. Press <kbd>⌘ cmd</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> to select the entire image and press <kbd>⌘ cmd</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> to copy it.

   [image]
3. Get Info (<kbd>⌘ cmd</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>) on the folder.
4. Click the folder icon on the top-left and press <kbd>⌘ cmd</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> to paste in the icon.

   [image]
   [image]

---

To revert back to the default blue folder…

1. Get Info on the folder.
2. Click your icon in the top-left.
3. Press <kbd>⌘ cmd</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>.

---

The folder icon is stored in the folder, as a hidden file.

```
.
└── Icon?
0 directories, 1 file
```

You can also remove the folder icon using the following Terminal command inside the folder with the icon that you wish to remove:

```
rm Icon$'\r'
```

Comment: Thats great. If you wanted to remove the image, to revert back to a blue folder (or indeed to change the image) - would you kindly explain that in your answer as well ?

Comment: Brilliant and you did it without even using Terminal, Applescript or Automator :)

Comment: HaHa and now you just went and spoilt it...LOL